# Is there a way to parcel a nodejs app which uses express and ejs?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, parceljs

I am trying to parcel my nodejs app which uses epxress and ejs but I am getting a parcel error during the process

My app already runs as expected if I use the standard way:
`node app.js`

However, when I try to run it with parcel I am getting an error.

my package.json (showing only relevant parts):

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel views/index.ejs",
    "build": "parcel build --public-url . views/index.ejs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "parcel-plugin-ejs": "^0.2.0",
    "parcel-plugin-ejs-template": "^0.1.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3"
  }
```

this is how I am rendering the page:

```
router.get("/" , function(req, res) {
  (async () => {
    const client = await pool.connect()
    try {
      const result = await client.query('select id, name from mytable')
      res.render("index", {
        items: result.rows
      })
    } finally {
      client.release()
    }
  })().catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
});
```

and my index.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>My website</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="menu">
    <% items.forEach(function(row){ %>
    <div class="item" data-value="<%= row.id %>"> <%= row.name %></div>
            <% }) %>
</div>
.
.
.
.

</body>

</html>
```

I would expect my app to be be parceled successfully and to be able to access it through the url provided.

However, I am getting this error:

```
$ npm run start

> my_project@1.0.0 start /home/user/my_project
> parcel views/index.ejs

Server running at http://localhost:1234 
  /home/user/my_project/views/index.ejs: items is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (/home/user/my_project/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:618:12), <anonymous>:5:8)
    at returnedFn (/home/user/my_project/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:653:17)
    at EjsAsset.generate (/home/user/my_project/node_modules/parcel-plugin-ejs-template/EjsAsset.js:30:12)
    at <anonymous>
```

Where items is just a list of products that I am sending from back-end with res.render() in order to create a drop-down.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add your index.ejs file and  nodes render code.

Comment: where to add it?

Comment: In your questions.

Comment: I have checked and no projects on github has used your package `parcel-plugin-ejs` ever. This may mean that package you are using is actually not well tested and may not even be working properly at all. I would suggest to get in touch with author of that package and check if this is a plugin issue or your approach issue. Also to me your approach seems a bit wrong, I believe parcel expects the entrypoint to your app, which is not the ejs file in your case. An example https://github.com/azdanov/voting-app-node/blob/5bb8d220b29bc4e63798a1a5b2c511740858ce33/package.json#L20

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, i will try them out

Answer (score -1):

maybe if you change the parts of the **start** and **build** scripts where you have *views/index.ejs* for *index.ejs*